# Custom route SailsJS and Socket

Tags: sockets, websocket, sails.js

O would like to use a custom method with socket on SailsJS.

```
new: function(req, res){

    Talk.create({message: "text"}).exec(function created(err,created){
        Talk.publishCreate(created);
        res.send(created);
    });
}
```

On client side I am doing exactly as described here: http://beta.sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/websockets/resourceful-pubsub/publishCreate.html

publishCreate are not sending updates to client side. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the problem is that you have not used the `.watch()` method to subscribe to `create` messages, as stated in the documentation you linked to:

> The default implementation of publishCreate only publishes messages to
>   the firehose, and to sockets subscribed to the model class using the
>   watch method

In the latest releases of Sails, the `sails.config.blueprints.autoWatch` property defaults to `true`, meaning that a socket will automatically start listening for "create" messages whenever it does a "find" call, as in `io.sockets.get('/talk')`.  Otherwise, you need to subscribe the socket manually in your controller using `Talk.watch(req);`.